# Retrieve cell numbers on condition in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I need to retrieve some cell numbers to used in another function.

Basically, I need a function that can test a condition and retrieve the row numbers which can then be appended with the column letter of my choice.
The function is of the form `getcolnumbers(range;criteria;'column_letter_to_be_appended_to_the_numbers_retrieved')`

```
E.g:
=getcolnumbers(A1:A10;5130;'B')

Ans: If the condition is satisfied in A3,A5,A8, then the return value should be 'B3;B5;B8'
```

is there such a function available in Excel?

Comment: No, you would need to write one using VBA - have you tried?

Comment: @MacroMan I am trying. i am really new to macros

Comment: I was going to edit your question, but given that the inconsistency exists in your macro as well, I thought it more prudent to point it out here and let you edit your own question:   You have columns and rows reversed in your mind.  Columns are lettered (A, B, C etc) and run vertically, rows are numbered (1, 2, 3 etc) and run horizontally.  Conceptually, the question is not flawed, but for the future you will get better answers if you use the correct vocabulary

Comment: @RGA Sorry about that. Thank you for pointing out

Comment: No need to apologize, just trying to help you get the best answers you can :)

Answer (score 2):

You can make your own User Defined Function:

```
Public Function getcolnumbers(r1 As Range, v As Variant, colid As String) As String
    Dim r As Range

    getcolnumbers = ""
    For Each r In r1
        If r.Value = v Then
            getcolnumbers = getcolnumbers & ";" & colid & r.Row
        End If
    Next r
    If Len(getcolnumbers) > 1 Then getcolnumbers = Mid(getcolnumbers, 2)
End Function
```

for example:

[image]

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

=myfunction(A1)

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

***(NOTE:  you may need to use a semi-colon in place of the comma when entering the formula in a worksheet cell)***

Comment: Hi, It works. One slight problem. I am using the result in another function. I checked the evaluation steps. (I am trying to use it in the getcolorcount function

`=getcolorcount("K21;K24;K28";W23)` Results in an error

Comment: Should I convert the string to Range?

Comment: @EchchamaNayak  I do not know......the problem may be the difference between ***semi-colon*** notation and the ***comma*** notation

Comment: @EchchamaNayak  Sine mu UDF()  returns a string of cell addresses, consider enclosing it within the *INDIRECT()* function ??

Comment: In my sheet cells are separated by semi colon and so are the parameters

Comment: Gives me a `#REF` Error

Comment: @EchchamaNayak  have the first parameter of *getcolorcount()* be a *String* and then within *getcolorcount()* parse that string to get the individual addresses.

Comment: @EchchamaNayak  **Post your *getcolorcount()* code.**

Comment: Also another problem, Sheet is not added

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this may be to break your procedure into additional columns. For example, add a column C, where

```
C1 = if(A1 > 5130, B1, "")
```

Then column C will only contain the values of column B that you want, based on the criteria you give for column A.